# Solving function $f(x) = \cos(\sin^{–1}(\tan(\cos^{–1}x)))$

Tags: functions, trigonometry

Consider the function $f(x) = \cos(\sin^{–1}(\tan(\cos^{–1}x)))$. .If number of solutions of equation $f(f(x)) =f(x)$ is $k$, then find the value of $k$.

I managed to find the domain and range of $f(x)$ by using basic inverse trigonometry function.

Domain of $f(x)$ is $x \in\big[-1,-\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\big]\cup\big[\frac{1}{\sqrt 2},1\big]$ and range of $f(x)$ is $[0,1]$ which is correct , I am not able to proceed ahead of it.

Comment: What if you try to express $tan(sin^{-1}(x)) $? To begin. Then $cos(arcsin)$, then write the complete expression of $f(f(x))$

Comment: Note the domains of the inverse trig functions.

Comment: I plotted the graph using the symbolic computing software Wolfram Mathematica, and found that the number of solutions is $k = 2$.

Comment: Use $|\cos(x)|=\sqrt{1-\sin^2(x)}$ and $|\tan(x)|=\sqrt{\frac1{\cos^2(x)}-1}$ for suitable $x$